# Campos formset en DetailView

Tags: django, django-forms

Tengo dos modelos relacionados y no logro ver los campos del modelo hijo en el DetailView (no logro solucionarlo).

he visto los siguientes temas similares, pero a mi no me funciona 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603425/accessing-child-model-via-detailview (muy similar)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592065/detailview-for-django-formset

Al crear los registros (CreateView) los campos se guardan en ambos modelos.
Al hacer UpdateView puedo ver todos los campos (modelo y modelo hijo), pero al hacer DetailView no puedo ver los datos del modelo hijo.

¿Cual seria la forma correcta de hacerlo? ¿Que me recomiendan?
Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

```
class Coti(models.Model):

tipo_servicio = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Cotización Arriendo",
                                 help_text="Ingrese tipo de servicio")
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
nombre_empresa = models.ForeignKey('clientes.Clientes', to_field='nombre_empresa', on_delete=models.PROTECT, help_text='Ingrese nombre empresa', related_name='Coti', default='Empresa')
proyecto = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Ingrese proyecto cotización")
ubicacion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Ingrese ubicacion de proyecto")

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-fecha',)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.nombre_empresa)
```

Este seria el modelo hijo

```
class tabla_coti(models.Model):
cotizacion = models.ForeignKey('Coti', related_name='tabla', verbose_name='Cotización', on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=0)
cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=1)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Ingrese ítem a cotizar")
valor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
subtotal = models.IntegerField(default=0)
valor_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('descripcion',)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.descripcion)
```

urls

```
path('coti/detail/<int:pk>', views.CotiTabla_cotiDetail.as_view(), name='coti-detail'),
```

vista

```
class CotiTabla_cotiDetail(DetailView):
model = Coti
queryset = Coti.objects.all()
success_url = reverse_lazy('coti:coti-list')
```

Template

Aquí solo puedo ver {{ coti.nombre_empresa }} {{ coti.proyecto }} {{ coti.ubicacion }} pero el for nada.

```
<div class="col-6">
    {{ coti.nombre_empresa }}  {{ coti.proyecto }} {{ coti.ubicacion }}
    {% for tabla in coti.tabla_set.all %}
    <p>  {{ tabla.descripcion }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Muestra tus modelos y tus vistas para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Intenta en el `for`, con esto: `coti.tabla.all`, y dime que pasa.

Comment: Espectacular..!! funcionó..!!
GRACIAS.
Seguiré probando...

Comment: OK un gusto poder ayudarte, recuerda que estas utilizando el `related_name` en tu relación, no te recomiendo hacerlo a menos de que tengas varias. Y por cierto es de mal practica utilizar snake_case en el nombre de las clases, utiliza CamelCase, así: `TablaCoti`.

Comment: Al usar el nombre del modelo coti.tabla_coti_set.all (borrando el related_name) ¿debería funcionar?

Comment: Creo que si, no lo se, ya que no sigues las convenciones.